# How to have functional button in Java?

Tags: java

I am new in programing and I need help.
How to have functional buttons in Java?
Check test code here:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
public class test {
    test(){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Flow Layout");
        JButton button;
        button = new JButton("button 1");

        frame.add(button);

        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        frame.setSize(300,300);  
        frame.setVisible(true);   

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new test();
    }

}
```

Comment: Please refer to this [How to Write an Action Listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add an `ActionListaner` to your button, in which you define what to do when it is clicked

```
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){  
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {  
     // do whatever 
   }  
});
```